# Plot three values x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame and I would like to plot as show the Figure 1.

- My data frame has three column.
- Each line must be plot on the same X-axis (three values by X-axis, as show the Figure 1).
- It has a line that passing between the middle values (in this case, line [1, V2], [2, V2], [3, V2]... [n, V2].

  [image: List item]

### Figure 1.

Figure 1 is only an example. I know the values are wrong in the plot.

Comment: It looks like you just want to plot a line with error bars. Take a look at the [`ggplot2`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html) package where you'd use `geom_line` for V2 and `geom_errorbar` with V1 and V3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I echo @divibisan's comment that if you just quickly want a plot with error bars, then you should take a look at `ggplot2::geom_errorbar`.

However, if you want fine control over each aspect of the plotting surface, but at the expense of a lot more typing, then here's one way to proceed:

```
# example data
randos <- runif(5, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(
    v1 = randos,
    v2 = randos+1,
    v3 = randos+2
)

# create empty plot
plot(x=1:nrow(df), y=1:nrow(df), pch=NA, # plot some data but don't show it
    ylim=c(0, ceiling(max(df)+2)),       # adjust y axis limit
    xaxt="n", yaxt="n",                  # remove axes
    bty="n",                             # remove box around plot
    xlab="", ylab="", main="")           # label axes and title

# add vertical lines
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    points(x=c(i,i), y=c(df$v1[i], df$v3[i]), type="l")
}

# add horizontal lines
points(x=1:nrow(df), y=df$v2, type="l")

# add points
points(x=1:nrow(df), y=df$v1, pch=15, col="forestgreen")
points(x=1:nrow(df), y=df$v2, pch=19, col="forestgreen")
points(x=1:nrow(df), y=df$v3, pch=8,  col="forestgreen")

# add back axes
axis(side=1, 1:nrow(df))
axis(side=2, 0:(ceiling(max(df))+2))

# an example of how to add text
text(x=1:nrow(df), y=df$v3, labels=format(df$v3,digits=2), pos=3)
```

[image: example_plot]